# this/context problem in touchable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a touchable Navigation. Therefore i have two states, the component gets rendered by: chosen and unchosen. On Press they change their state and get chosen. This works just fine with the Text View, but with my own view, it doesn't work anymore, even though it is inside a touchable view.

How it should work:
http://www.giphy.com/gifs/Wmczw6pwf1ssUNIDkV

Not working with my custom View(even though both are wrapped by a Touchable Opacity>
http://www.giphy.com/gifs/XG718bNUbQq4Il1g69

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, FlatList, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableHighlight  , Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Header, TopNavigationButton, TopNavigationButtonUnchosen}  from './components';



type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {


constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    topNavigationOptions : [
      {key: 'Quick Search'},
      {key: 'Person Search'},],
    chosenTopNavigation: 
      "Quick Search"
  };


}


renderItem = ({item}) => {
  if (item.key == this.state.chosenTopNavigation) {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = { () => this.setState({chosenTopNavigation: item.key}) }  >
        <TopNavigationButton >
          {item.key}
        </TopNavigationButton>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      )
  } else {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = { () => this.setState({chosenTopNavigation: item.key}) }>




        //if i use a standard Text component, it swiches state and rerenders just fine, but with my View it does not work.
        <TopNavigationButtonUnchosen>
          {item.key}
        </TopNavigationButtonUnchosen>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
  }
}


  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress= {this._onPressButton}>
          <Header>Kopf</Header>
        </TouchableHighlight>


        <ScrollView horizontal = {true}>
          <View style = {styles.navigationContainer}>
            <TopNavigationButton>Quick Search</TopNavigationButton>
            <Text style = {styles.unchosenTextStyle}>Person Search</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      <View styles = {styles.navigationContainer}>  
        <FlatList 
          horizontal
          extraData = {this.state.chosenTopNavigation}
          data={this.state.topNavigationOptions}
          renderItem = {this.renderItem.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
      </View>  
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({


  navigationContainer: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginTop: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  unchosenTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 17,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
          fontFamily: "OpenSans-Bold"
      },
      android: {
          fontFamily: "opensansBold"
      }
    }),
    color: '#9AA5B1',
    marginLeft: 20
  }
});
```

Custom Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet,Platform} from 'react-native';

const TopNavigationButtonUnchosen = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style = {styles.navigationBackgroundSelected}>
            <Text style = {styles.navigationBackgroundSelectedText}>{props.children}</Text> 
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    navigationBackgroundSelected:{
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        borderRadius: 16,
        //opacity: 0.6, lasst auch das Child schlechter Aussehen
      },
      navigationBackgroundSelectedText:{
        paddingTop:5,
        paddingBottom:5,
        paddingLeft:15,
        paddingRight:15,
        fontSize:17,
        color:'#9AA5B1', 
        ...Platform.select({
          ios: {
              fontFamily: "OpenSans-Bold"
          },
          android: {
              fontFamily: "opensansBold"
          }
      }),  
    }
})


export {TopNavigationButtonUnchosen} ;
```

TopNavigationButtonUnchosen is a normal functional Component, just a bit styling. Thanks a lot for your help, really cannot explain this weird behavior to myself

Note: Upon testing i was able to find out, that TouchableOpacity is simply not working when used with a custo component. I assume its got something to do with my onpress function being on this. Any ideas are much appreciated

Comment: Could you share the code for the custom components?

Comment: Did , so hope it helps! As far as my understanding goes, it shouldnt influence the behavior at all though, but probably I am missing something there